# Tag Synonyms Queue

Tags: discussion

I remember reading on here that one of the reasons the Tag Synonyms privilege is to high in rep list, is due to the size of the current queue.

What if the Tag Synonyms approval process was taken to the community?

A proposal for an alias could be put up for `voting` by the community for a specific amount of time. Of course, there'd be a rep requirement for those who can participate in voting.

Perhaps there could even be a way to comment and discuss alias proposals.

This would take the load off the mods, and ought to clean up the queue.

Comment: Isn't it *already* done like this?

Comment: Is it? I don't see any way to participate on: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms I don't believe non-mods can participate. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: It just requires high rep and a high score in *every tag you vote on*.

Comment: Perhaps that could be changed to a lower rep, to cut down on the queue? It's currently over 20 pages long.

Comment: The user interface is bad enough that many people just don't care to vote. Review the list, find a reasonable synonym, and click to vote - the popup says "you don't have enough score on this tag". Doh!